# Global keyhook for mediakeys in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, keyhook, media-keys

With the following `RegisterHotKey` function, I can globally hook normal key-modifier combinations:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
```

Great article about it and full source code here: http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207

But the question is, how do I hook Media Keys, those play/pause/next/previous -keys found in keyboards and pc remotes? I have googled and googled, but without any luck.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.MediaPlayPause`, `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Play`, etc. values for the **vk** parameter (after casting it to **uint**) and **0** for the **fsModifiers** (unles you want to register for Shift-Play, Alt-Play or other key combinations).

Comment: I tried, but it does not work with my keyboard (Logitech Illuminated Keyboard K740). Media Keys works normally with other media applications, but not with C# System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Media*. There's also no luck with any normal KeyEvent, C# just does not recognize my media keys. Only way I can handle media keys, is to override WndProc, and check for WM_APPCOMMAND, but with that I cannot get global hotkeys. Other ideas?